# Can we verify a method invocation that we have already registered to return something by when

Tags: mockito

```
class service {
    public String serviceMethod(String A, Object B) {
         //Does something
    }
}

@Mock
service serviceobj;
```

I have mocked service class and because this is a service call, I have mocked the output.

Like:

```
Mockito.when(serviceobj.serviceMethod(Mockito.eq(A)), Mockito.isA(Object.class)).thenReturn("Reply from Service");
```

The Question is very simple. 
I want to verify a method invocation, using Mockito.verify.

```
Mockito.verify(serviceobj).serviceMethod(Mockito.eq(A)), Mockito.isA(Object.class));
```

But I get an error, there are zero invocations with this mock.
I just want to know that this is possible or not?

Comment: try to add the full stacktrace

Comment: also add the invocation of the method

Comment: I am just asking that this is possible or not? If yes, then I will invest some time into the debugging. I don't want to invest time into something that is not allowed by Mockito.

Comment: i invested 3 minutes and recreated the scenario.. and it worked without your exception.. so it is possible.. you simply are making some small mistake that is not clear without the full picture.